# how can I re-disable the hot corner in gnome-shell 40?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I used to disable gnome-shell's hot corner feature with the [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) extension. Upgrading to gnome-shell 40 has it deprecated. [Gnome-tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) claims it's able to disable it as well, but activating this "disable the hot-corner" option doesn't deactivate the hot corner at all. Finally, I found reading [this Ask Ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701592/how-do-i-disable-activities-hot-corner-in-gnome-shell) that I could

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners false
```

but it doesn't work either, even though the command succeeds.So this little Apple©-like annoyance is back.

So indeed the question is : how do I get rid of it again ? ... Hell I love you Gnome, but you're really stepping on my nerves from time to time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears I had to reboot for the `gsettings` command to take effect. And now that I did reboot, the command is taking effect immediately, meaning I can switch live the hotcorner feature with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners false
```

and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners true
```

I suppose that it did not work because the workstation was not rebooted since I had upgraded GNOME. Hope this documents this feature's behaviour as a whole.